# What will be the effect on monero if bitcoin deploys schnorr sig's?

Tags: ringct, privacy

Let's take this question two ways.

1. Assuming Schnorr requires a hard-fork - let's take into consideration what that could do to bitcoin in context of this question.
2. let's assume schnorr is deployed without major problem or impact to bitcoin (seems unlikely but would be very nice to see the community band together for something so fundamentally bitcoin as privacy). Does monero lose all it's advantage over bitcoin?

Sorry if this is too discussiony,trying to be more question oriented but the speculative nature of the question lends itself more to discussion.

Comment: I only say 'assuming that schnorr requires a hard-fork' because I've only read one source about schnorr, and they said it requires a HF. Makes sense, but I'm just covering my bases in case the person who wrote that was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know about Schnorr. But Imo, it's not the same lvl of privacy that monero offers. 
Plus, there's no interest for bitcoin to include anonimity in transactions. Bitcoin still suffers of its pseudo-anonimity. Even in 2016, there's still dumb political/financial reviews that point the btc as "money laudering, terrorist act, drugs implication" ...
Btc has never been and will never be an anonymous crypto and the fact that the btc is still rising and consolodidating after years is directly related to the fact that the bitcoin comunity want to prove his credentials as a concurrent of fiat currency.

Sorry for my english

Comment: thank goodness for monero! Hopefully bitcoin retains fungibility at the very least.